# How can I pass Interface to the child component in Typescript React application

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

```
interface User {
  name: string,
  address: string,
  active: boolean
}
```

The problem is -

I can't import interface in child component.
Child component interface have to be the type parent component provided.
So how can I access component props to define interface.

Comment: It's unclear what your problem is. Give a [mre] of child and parent and show the error.

Answer (score 4):

The interface that need to be imported need to be explicitly exported from the file where it is declared.

**Here is the working example for exporting an interface and importing it in a component:**

**Interface file  - IUser.ts**

```
// File name: IUser.ts

export interface IUser {
  name: string,
  address: string,
  active: boolean
}
```

**Component File  - Functional comopnent / React Hook**

```
// File name: MyComponent.tsx

import React, {FunctionComponent} from 'react'
import {IUser} from "../interfaces/IUser"


const MyComponent : FunctionComponent<IUser> = (props) => (
    <div>
        <div>Name: {props.name}</h2>
        <div>Address: {props.address}</div>
        <div>Active: {props.active}</div>
    </div>
)

export default MyComponent
```

**Component File  using Class**

```
// File name: MyComponent.tsx

import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {IUser} from "../interfaces/IUser"

export default class MyComponent extends Component<IUser> {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>Name: {this.props.name}</h2>
                <div>Address: {this.props.address}</div>
                <div>Active: {this.props.active}</div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

first you should export your interface like so:

```
export interface User {
name: string,
address: string,
active: boolean
}
```

then you can import it wherever you want:

```
import { User } from 'relative/path/to/interface'
```